# Spring Social and Facebook API Changes

Tags: java, facebook, spring-social

I'm thinking of using Spring Social to integrate with Facebook, but I've never done any kind of integration with it before, so this seems nice.  My only worry is if the Facebook changes their API somewhat often, it seems like we would have to wait for Spring Social to be updated.  Since this project unfortunately doesn't use Maven, that would be even more of a pain.

Does anyone else find this to be an issue, i.e. does Facebook alter its API enough for it to be a problem, or is there a large deprecation/backwards-compatibility period in order to give Spring Social time to update their API?

Comment: spring social is in the spring repository at http://repo.springsource.org/release
if there are changes to the facebook api you can commit the changes to spring social at github. i think the guys at spring will integrate those pretty fast... i mean they are getting paid to do this :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook likes to change and break their API all the time and they don't care for their developers.  On some of the changes they will give people advance notice (only if you check their blog very frequently) so 3rd party SDK's can have a chance to update but for every breaking change they announce, I could name a breaking change they didn't announce (just notice how they confirm nearly double the amounts of bugs each week and bugs that get fixed).